# can't trap CommitTrans in ADO OLEDB when it gives 0xc0000005 error

Tags: c++, sql, oledb, ado

When I try and do a CommitTrans, the 'catch' does not capture when the exception code 0xc0000005 happens:

```
_ConnectionPtr connection = NULL;
CoInitialize(NULL);
connection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
connection->CursorLocation = adUseClient;
connection->Open(sConnectionString,L"",L"",0);
connection->Execute(sSQL,NULL,adCmdText);

try
{
connection->CommitTrans();  // <- 0xc0000005 1. Why? 2. 'catch' doens't trap
}
catch(...)
{
DWORD dwErr;
dwErr;
}

recordset->Close();
recordset = NULL;
connection->Close();
connection=NULL;
CoUninitialize();
```

1. Why does CommitTrans fail here?
2. Why doesn't 'catch' trap the failure?

Answer (score 0):

To catch the 0xc0000005 exception you'll need to use Structured Exception Handling.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

```
Try the following code and you will see that the program print "__except" rather than "catch".

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    try
    {
        int *p = NULL;
        *p = 1;
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        std::cout << "catch\n";
    }
}

void bar()
{
    __try
    {
        foo();
    }
    __except ( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER )
    {
        std::cout << "__except\n";
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bar();
    std::cout << "success\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean I should have this? 

'try
{
connection->CommitTrans();
}
__except ( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER )
{
DWORD dwErr;
dwErr;
}'

Comment: That's __try.  And yes, that will enable you to catch the 0xc0000005 exception.  Assuming it's inside the call to CommitTrans that the exception is being thrown.

Comment: How do I know when to use "Structured Exception Handling" vs 'try'?